# Equivalent to UIWebView's paginationMode on WKWebView

Tags: ios, pagination, wkwebview

I'm changing a huge app that uses a lot of `UIWebViews` to use `WKWebViews`.

The app used to have this line `paginationMode = .rightToLeft` but `WKWebView` doesnt have this feature.

How can I get the UIWebView's right to left pagination in WKWebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it -
I added this to my `css` file

```
body {
    overflow: -webkit-paged-x !important;
    direction: rtl !important;
}
```

Watch out about WKWebview ignoring parts of your css... in that case add this as a prefix to your `Html` string -

```
"<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />"
```

or via helper method in an WKWebview extension

```
open func loadHTMLStringForWKWebview(_ string: String, baseURL: URL?)
    {
        // without this line WKWebview may ignore part in your css file
        let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />"
        loadHTMLString(headerString+string, baseURL: baseURL)
    }
```

make sure you add the right baseURL - in my case it is -

```
Bundle.main.bundleURL
```