# How can I paginate html in a wkwebview?

Tags: css, wkwebview

I want to paginate the content of a WKWebView so that it snaps to a full page when swiping left or right in the document.  I found part of the solution in this answer - [Equivalent to UIWebView's paginationMode on WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599461/equivalent-to-uiwebviews-paginationmode-on-wkwebview)

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't cover snapping.  I have implemented the following so far…

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSString *cssString = @"body { overflow: -webkit-paged-x !important; direction: ltr !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;  scroll-snap-align: center; }";
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)";
    NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString];
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptWithCSSString completionHandler:nil];
}
```

As you can see, I've added  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;  scroll-snap-align: center;`, although that hasn't helped the situation any.

The HTML that is being formatted can't be modified - and an example of the HTML (from an ebook) is shown here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>CHAPTER I | War and Peace</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/book.css" type="text/css"/>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>
      <meta name="EPB-UUID" content="7EA691AA-6C00-1014-AFE7-873900C99DD9"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="body">
         <div class="chapter">
            <h3 class="chapter-title">CHAPTER I</h3>
            <p>"Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don't tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist&#8212;I really believe he is Antichrist&#8212;I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my 'faithful slave,' as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you&#8212;sit down and tell me all the news."</p>
```

I can rely on `<body>` being there, but I don't think that I can rely on any of the divs being present in all documents.

Any idea on how I can get snapping to work for each page?