# How can I ignore all touch events in WKWebView and its enclosingScrolllView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

I have a WKWebView (discussed in this page - [How can I paginate html in a wkwebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095477/how-can-i-paginate-html-in-a-wkwebview)) and I'm trying a different approach to solving the problem discussed there.

What I want to do is trap scroll events in the view for the entire window (`[self.window.contentView setAllowedTouchTypes:(NSTouchTypeMaskDirect | NSTouchTypeMaskIndirect)];`) and then ignore all touch events for WKWebView and WKWebView's enclosing scrollview.

I can see that my `setAllowedTouchTypes` is working as follows…

```
@interface NSView ( TouchEvents )

@end

@implementation NSView ( TouchEvents )

- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touched");    
}

@end
```

Even though I can see the 'touched' messages in the logs, the contents of my WKWebView still scrolls around when I swipe with my fingers.  For this to work, I need it not to move at all!

Try as I might, I can't work out how to stop the swipes working for my WKWebView - and there doesn't seem to be anything in Interface Builder to achieve this aim either.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Which problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I've written a method which will perform the scroll in Javascript (it works well with buttons), so my intention is to trap a swipe in the window content view, determine its direction, and then execute that method.

Comment: Do you want to detect a swipe or do you want to prevent scrolling? Have you tried a gesture recognizer?

Comment: I tried adding a gesture recogniser to the the WKWebView - but it didn't seem to be detected reliably.  Which is why I ask about removing the recognisers from the enclosing scrollview.