# How can I page through an e-Book using WKWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, wkwebview

I've danced around this question previously, asking specific questions which I hoped might lead me to the next step in solving the larger problem.  That didn't work (no answers), so this is the larger problem.

Original questions
[How can I ignore all touch events in WKWebView and its enclosingScrolllView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76166846/how-can-i-ignore-all-touch-events-in-wkwebview-and-its-enclosingscrolllview)

[How can I paginate html in a wkwebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095477/how-can-i-paginate-html-in-a-wkwebview)

**Context**

Apple originally provided a very full featured and functional API for displaying HTML - WebView.  Many tools were written for WebView, for example to display the pages of an e-book.
WebView is now deprecated in favour of WKWebView, which 'feels' minimally functional - a lot of the features that made WebView easy to work with don't exist in WebView, and I can't find any tools for displaying the pages of an e-Book neatly.

I want to produce a tool which can be shared publicly on GitHub which will provide this e-book functionality, both so that I can benefit from it myself - but also so that everyone else can.

**Problem**

At minimum, this needs to work on macOS (I'll worry about iOS later)

So far, my code scrolls the book content neatly one page at a time if you press the buttons - but if you swipe on the mouse or trackpad (guessing here) acceleration ruins the functionality (it should work in the same way as pressing the buttons).  I can get it so that a swipe will move the book content along by one page - but once the page has been updated the acceleration / deceleration effect of the swipe continues - and the page moves on past the point where it should have stopped moving.

The page scroll is horizontal.

The code I have so far is

```
//
//  ReaderWindowController.m
//

#import "ReaderWindowController.h"
#import "LibrarianFormatPluginInterface.h"

#define WindowSideLeft 0
#define WindowSideRight 1

@interface WKWebView (SynchronousEvaluateJavaScript)
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;
@end

@implementation WKWebView (SynchronousEvaluateJavaScript)

- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script {
    __block NSString *resultString = nil;
    __block BOOL finished = NO;
    
    [self evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            if (result != nil) {
                resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        finished = YES;
    }];
    
    while (!finished) {
        [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:NSDate.distantFuture];
    }
    
    return resultString;
}

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Scrolled wheel");
}

- (BOOL)scrollRectToVisible:(NSRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Scroll rect to visible %f x %f , %f x %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    
    return true;
}

- (void)scrollClipView:(NSClipView *)clipView toPoint:(NSPoint)point {
    NSLog(@"Scroll clip view %@ to point %f x %f", clipView, point.x, point.y);
}

- (NSRect)adjustScroll:(NSRect)newVisible {
    NSRect modifiedRect=newVisible;
    
    // snap to 72 pixel increments
    modifiedRect.origin.x = (int)(modifiedRect.origin.x/72.0) * 72.0;
    //        modifiedRect.origin.y = (int)(modifiedRect.origin.y/72.0) * 72.0;
    
    // return the modified rectangle
    return modifiedRect;
}

- (void)scrollRangeToVisible:(NSRange)range {
    NSLog(@"Scroll range to visible");
}

- (void)scrollPoint:(NSPoint)point {
    NSLog(@"Scroll point to visible");
}

- (void)reflectScrolledClipView:(NSClipView *)clipView {
    NSLog(@"reflectScrolledClipView point to visible");
}

@end


@interface NSView ( TouchEvents )

@end

@implementation NSView ( TouchEvents )

float beginX, endX;


- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    if(event.type == NSEventTypeGesture){
        NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:self];
        if(touches.count == 2){
            for (NSTouch *touch in touches) {
                beginX = touch.normalizedPosition.x;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEndedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    
    if(event.type == NSEventTypeGesture){
        NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:self];
        NSDictionary* userInfo;
        if(touches.count == 2){
            for (NSTouch *touch in touches) {
                endX = touch.normalizedPosition.x;
            }
            // since there are two touches, endX will always end up with the data from the second touch
            
            if (endX > beginX) {
                NSLog(@"swipe right!");
                userInfo = @{@"direction": @(WindowSideRight)};
            }
            else if (endX < beginX) {
                NSLog(@"swipe left!");
                userInfo = @{@"direction": @(WindowSideLeft)};
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"no swipe!");
            }
            
            [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:@"pageScrollEvent" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        }
    }
    
}

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"user scrolled %f horizontally and %f vertically", [event deltaX], [event deltaY]);
}

@end


@interface ReaderWindowController ()

@end

@implementation ReaderWindowController

- (void)createButtonOnSide:(int)side withSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    int x = 0, y = 100, width = 40, height = 230;
    NSRect framesize = NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height);
    
    NSString* label = side==WindowSideLeft?@"<":@">";
    
    NSButton *myButton = [NSButton.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [myButton setButtonType:NSButtonTypeMomentaryPushIn];
    if (@available(macOS 11.0, *)) {
        NSImage* arrow = side==WindowSideLeft?[NSImage imageWithSystemSymbolName:@"arrowshape.left.fill" accessibilityDescription:label]:[NSImage imageWithSystemSymbolName:@"arrowshape.right.fill" accessibilityDescription:label];
        [myButton setImage:arrow];
    } else {
        [myButton setTitle:label];
    }
    [myButton setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleTexturedSquare];
    [myButton setTarget:self];
    [myButton setAction:aSelector];
    [myButton setTag:side];
    
    myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:framesize.size.width].active = YES;
    [myButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:framesize.size.height].active = YES;
    [myButton.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.window.contentView.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
    if (side == WindowSideLeft) {
        [myButton.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.window.contentView.leadingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    } else {
        [myButton.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.window.contentView.trailingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    }
    
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [NSTrackingArea.alloc
                                    initWithRect:myButton.bounds
                                    options: NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways
                                    owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"entered");
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"exited");
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [self.window setDelegate:self];
    
    [bookPages setAllowedTouchTypes:(NSTouchTypeMaskDirect | NSTouchTypeMaskIndirect)];
    
    [self.window setAppearance:[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua]];
    
    [bookPages setNavigationDelegate:self];
    pageCount = 0; // might want to load this from preferences
    
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(loadDidFinish:)
                                               name:@"LoadDidFinishNotification"
                                             object:nil];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(buttonPressed:)
                                               name:@"PageScrollEvent"
                                             object:nil];
    
    [self createButtonOnSide:WindowSideLeft withSelector:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    [self createButtonOnSide:WindowSideRight withSelector:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    
}

- (id)initWithBookPlugin:(id)bookPlug andWindowController:(NSNibName)windowNibName {
    if (bookPlug && ![[bookPlug className] isEqualToString:[NSNull className]] && (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName])) {
        bookPlugin = bookPlug;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSURLRequest* thisRequest = [bookPlugin getURLRequestForIndex:8];
    [bookPages loadRequest:thisRequest];
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self];
    if (bookPlugin) { bookPlugin = nil; }
}

-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSString *cssString = @"body { overflow: -webkit-paged-x !important; direction: ltr !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;  scroll-snap-align: center; }";
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)";
    NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString];
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptWithCSSString completionHandler:nil];
}

-(NSSize)getViewDimensionsForwebView:(WKWebView *)webView {
    NSString* width = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"Math.max( document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth )"];
    NSString* height = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight )"];
    
    return NSMakeSize(width.floatValue,height.floatValue);
}

- (void) updateAfterDelay:(id)sender {
    [self buttonPressed:nil];
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([[sender className] isEqualToString:@"NSButton"]) {
        if ([sender tag] == WindowSideLeft) { pageCount--; } else { pageCount++; }
    } else if ([[sender className] isEqualToString:@"NSConcreteNotification"]) {
        if ([[sender userInfo][@"direction"] isEqualTo: @(WindowSideLeft)]) { pageCount--; } else { pageCount++; }
    }
    
    pageCount = pageCount<0?0:pageCount;
    NSInteger pageWidth = self.window.contentView.frame.size.width;
    
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: %ld, behavior: \"smooth\",});", pageWidth * pageCount];
    [bookPages evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];

    if (sender != nil) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateAfterDelay:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.75];
    }

}



@end
```

I'd love to hear what I'm doing wrong here - but I'd also be happy to hear of any project which does the same thing (provided that it doesn't contain any deprecations)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the provided code aims to implement e-book functionality using WKWebView on macOS. However, there are issues with touch event handling and achieving smooth scrolling. To ignore touch events in WKWebView, override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method in the NSView category (TouchEvents) and return `nil`.

For pagination, modify the `webView:didFinishNavigation:` delegate method to set the CSS properties `column-count` and `column-gap` of the body element to achieve a single column layout without gaps.

To achieve smooth scrolling, modify the `buttonPressed:` method. Use `scrollTo` with `behavior: "smooth"` in JavaScript to scroll to the desired position smoothly.

Here's a suggested modification to the `buttonPressed:` method:

```objectivec
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([[sender className] isEqualToString:@"NSButton"]) {
        if ([sender tag] == WindowSideLeft) {
            pageCount--;
        } else {
            pageCount++;
        }
    } else if ([[sender className] isEqualToString:@"NSConcreteNotification"]) {
        if ([[sender userInfo][@"direction"] isEqualTo: @(WindowSideLeft)]) {
            pageCount--;
        } else {
            pageCount++;
        }
    }
    
    pageCount = MAX(pageCount, 0);
    NSInteger pageWidth = self.window.contentView.frame.size.width;
    
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: %ld, behavior: \"smooth\"});", pageWidth * pageCount];
    [bookPages evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference. `hitTest:withEvent:` is a UIView method, not an NSView method.  I did have another idea - a very hacky workaround - which kind of, sort of, if you squint does what I need.  But not really.  See code above which has been updated accordingly.